# Drinfeld center of a tensor category

Tags: ct.category-theory, c-star-algebras, lattices, hilbert-spaces

Firstly, apologies for the imprecise language, I'm a physicist trying to understand anyonic excitations from the lens of category theory.

If I have a category (say $\operatorname{Rep}(\mathbb{Z}_2)$) then computing its Drinfeld centre will give you the anyonic excitations in the quantum double models (In this case: 1, e, m, $\psi$). The category corresponding to these excitations should be the $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ UMTC (Is my assumption correct?).

My question is, does this construction always give you the anyonic excitations possible in a category? Or do we need access to more information in order to uniquely determine the possible excitations?

For example, in the lattice language, I need to be given a Hilbert space (which is the category $\operatorname{Rep}(\mathbb{Z}_2)$) and a Hamiltonian, from which I will find the ground state, and all possible superselection sectors in the Hilbert space (These would be the excitations 1, e, m, $\psi$).

The additional information required on the lattice side of things is the "Hamiltonian" or more generally the C* algebra for the system. So does computing the centre of a category also somehow determine the C* algebra? If not, what additional info do I need to know for certain what excitations would be possible in my system?